# How to check if a textArea is empty and enable or disable a particular button?

Tags: javascript

It is coming with the button disabled, however as soon as I write something in the textArea the button does not enable!

**MY CODE:**

```
function teste(){
  btnEnviar = document.getElementById('btnAnalisarImagem');
  txtAreaInserirURLImagem = document.getElementById('inserirURLImagem').value;

  if(!txtAreaInserirURLImagem){
    return btnEnviar.disabled = true;
  } else {
    return btnEnviar.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you actually calling that function?

Comment: Why are you returning a value?

Comment: Why not just assign `disabled` to your boolean directly?

Comment: you should at least use an event like onkeyUp to call your function, call the on key up event of the textarea

Comment: @SLaks Yes, so much that the button is already disabled.

Comment: @ThiagoSaad: Do you ever call it again so that the button can be re-enabled?

Comment: @jidexl21 This Worked for me. Write this answer here that i will give your points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this snippet like so

```
btnEnviar = document.getElementById('btnAnalisarImagem');
btnEnviar.onKeyUp = teste
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your function again when the contents change, typically by handling events like `keyup` or (to handle other changes like pasting) `input`.